# How to hide Request Payload from network (developer tool) in chrome, firefox or safari through Node JS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Rest API created in Node JS, for POST request i am passing body in JSON format, when i hit api all data coming with proper JSON format in Network Tab of developer console.

I want to hide my request payload.as exposing key might create problem.

I am working over HTTP.

Comment: Don't expose your key in your client-side code. There is nothing you can do to hide this info from Chrome DevTools with your existing architecture.

Comment: @yogesh Even I need to achieve the similar thing. Did you got the solution?